# My different sessions are being duplicated with the same last activity and session id, why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using spring security, when i log in from different browsers with the same user (which i set to be possible to have multiple sessions), the data passed from the controller (where i get the SessionInformation from every principal) to the View is being duplicated instead of creating a new Session Id and the Last Activity is the very same for all the different browser sessions as well.

This is a part of the spring-security.xml where the sessionRegistry is configured and stuff.

```
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" always-use-default-target="true"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />

        <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
        <custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter" />   
        <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider">
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
       class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
      <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="myAuthFilter" class=
       "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
      <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
      <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sas" class=
     "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
      <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
      <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="-1" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" 
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

This is the Controller on which the sessionRegistry is being consumed:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/activeusers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String manageActiveUsers(ModelMap model, Principal principal) {
        String name = principal.getName();
        model.addAttribute("username", name);
        List<LoginUserInfo> userSessionData = new ArrayList<LoginUserInfo>();       

        List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();

        //TODO: Find a better way to get the remote IP Address according to each client call
        String remoteAddress = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
           .getRequest().getLocalAddr();

        for (Object object : principals) {
            LoginUserInfo userInfo = new LoginUserInfo();
            LdapUserDetailsImpl user = (LdapUserDetailsImpl) object;
            List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(user, false);
            String username = user.getUsername();

            for (SessionInformation session : sessions) {
                Date lastRequest = session.getLastRequest();
                String sessionId = session.getSessionId();

                userInfo.setUsername(username);
                userInfo.setIp(remoteAddress);
                userInfo.setLastActivity(lastRequest.getTime());
                userInfo.setSessionId(sessionId);

                userSessionData.add(userInfo);
            }           
        }

        model.addAttribute("userSessionData", userSessionData);

        return "activeusers";
    }
```

And then i send "userSessionData" to a jsp VIEW like this.

```
                  <c:forEach var="userDetail" items="${userSessionData}">
                      <tr>
                        <td><c:out value="${userDetail.ip}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${userDetail.username}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${userDetail.lastActivity}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${userDetail.sessionId}"/></td>
                      </tr>
                   </c:forEach>
```

As i said, all the user related data is being duplicated (sessionId and lastActivity) even though i log in from another browser. When i do some requests from one browser, the lastActivity gets refreshed in all the sessions at the same time.

Another thing, when i log out from different browsers, the session should be terminated. But when i check the session List, is still there. Why is that happening too???

Comment: Can you give more details about what you do, what is wrong, your code and your configuration?

Comment: Done, updated, thanks btw for replying @WilQu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem with your sessions, it's a problem with your `for` loops.

You create only one `LoginUserInfos` per user, and this object is reused for each session. As a result, you only see the data of the last session. Create the `LoginUserInfos` in the inner loop instead.

```
    for (Object object : principals) {
        LdapUserDetailsImpl user = (LdapUserDetailsImpl) object;
        List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(user, false);
        String username = user.getUsername();

        for (SessionInformation session : sessions) {
            LoginUserInfo userInfo = new LoginUserInfo();
            Date lastRequest = session.getLastRequest();
            String sessionId = session.getSessionId();

            userInfo.setUsername(username);
            userInfo.setIp(remoteAddress);
            userInfo.setLastActivity(lastRequest.getTime());
            userInfo.setSessionId(sessionId);

            userSessionData.add(userInfo);
        }           
    }
```

This should give you the expected results.

Comment: lol thanks you were right! But how do i remove the session from the session list after i log out from one session the spring way (j_spring_security_logout) ?

Comment: @msqar I don't know how to force it. I would let the server manage sessions.

Comment: okey :) thanks for all your help WilQu, i will mark it as solved! Can't believe i couldn't see that error in the loop, maybe coz i modified it a lot in the progress.